# PrestaShop WebService - Price Update for various products

Tags: php, mysql, web-services, prestashop, prestashop-1.6

I have this to update the PrestaShop price for one product with the WebService.

```
    <html><head><title>CRUD Data Transfer - Update example</title></head><body>
<?php
// Here we define constants /!\ You need to replace this parameters
define('DEBUG', true);
define('PS_SHOP_PATH', 'https://my.domain.com');
define('ID_PRODUCT', 1);
define('PS_WS_AUTH_KEY', 'XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX');
require_once('./PSWebServiceLibrary.php');
@ini_set('display_errors', 'on');
try
{
$webService = new PrestaShopWebservice(PS_SHOP_PATH, PS_WS_AUTH_KEY, DEBUG);
$opt = array('resource' => 'products');
$opt['id']=ID_PRODUCT;
$xml = $webService->get($opt);
echo "Successfully recived data.";
     /* List of nodes that can't modify
     *
     *  - "manufacturer_name"
     *  - "position_in_category"
     *  - "quantity"
     *  - "type"
     */
    unset($xml->children()->children()->manufacturer_name);
    unset($xml->children()->children()->position_in_category);
    unset($xml->children()->children()->quantity);
    unset($xml->children()->children()->type);
   $xml->children()->children()->price = 111.0; // <-- new price!
//Load new data to query generator
$opt['putXml']=$xml->asXML();
$xml = $webService->edit($opt);
// if WebService don't throw an exception the action worked well and we don't show the following message
echo "Successfully updated.";
}
catch (PrestaShopWebserviceException $ex)
{
// Here we are dealing with errors
$trace = $ex->getTrace();
if ($trace[0]['args'][0] == 404) echo 'Bad ID';
else if ($trace[0]['args'][0] == 401) echo 'Bad auth key';
else echo 'Other error<br />'.$ex->getMessage();
}

?>
</body></html>
```

How can i do the same, but for all the products in a MySQL table?

I have all the products in a MySQL table with the ID Key as Source_ID.

Appreciate any help!

Regards

Comment: nothing ?? :( i really need this please!!

Comment: Did you get any solution for this? I'm in same task now , can you help me if you have solution for update multiple product price.

Answer (score 0):

You'll need to retrieve the product data for each product, update it's price, and then save it.
Try something like this:

```
<html><head><title>CRUD Data Transfer - Update example</title></head><body>
<?php
// Here we define constants /!\ You need to replace this parameters
define('DEBUG', true);
define('PS_SHOP_PATH', 'http://my.domain.com');
define('PS_WS_AUTH_KEY', 'XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX');
require_once('PSWebServiceLibrary.php');
@ini_set('display_errors', 'on');

try {
    $webService = new PrestaShopWebservice(PS_SHOP_PATH, PS_WS_AUTH_KEY, DEBUG);

    // Get products from your database via a query
    $products = array(array('id' => 1, 'price' => 1.5,), array('id' => 2, 'price' => 2.95));

    // Loop through products
    foreach ($products as $product) {

        $opt = array('resource' => 'products', 'id' => $product['id']);

        // Call webservice to get product data
        $xml = $webService->get($opt);

        // Remove nodes that can't be modified
        unset($xml->children()->children()->manufacturer_name);
        unset($xml->children()->children()->position_in_category);
        unset($xml->children()->children()->quantity);
        unset($xml->children()->children()->type);

        // Update product data
        $xml->children()->children()->price = $product['price']; // <-- new price!

        // Load new data to query generator        
        $opt['putXml'] = $xml->asXML();

        // Save product
        $xml = $webService->edit($opt);
        // if WebService don't throw an exception the action worked well and we don't show the following message
    }
} catch (PrestaShopWebserviceException $ex) {
    // Here we are dealing with errors
    $trace = $ex->getTrace();
    if ($trace[0]['args'][0] == 404)
        echo 'Bad ID';
    else if ($trace[0]['args'][0] == 401)
        echo 'Bad auth key';
    else
        echo 'Other error<br />' . $ex->getMessage();
}
?>
</body></html>
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: Thanks for your help!

For the moment, i have tried with yours, but it only update the first product:

'id' => 1, 'price' => 1.5

The other one is not updated. :(

Comment: Oh that's sad :-( Do you get an error on the update? Does a product with ID 2 actually exist in your shop?

Comment: Hello @ArisS No, i have this at the end: Other error
This call to PrestaShop Web Services failed and returned an HTTP status of 500. That means: Internal Server Error.

for your other question, yes, i have actually 3 products in my shop with id 1,2 and 3.

Comment: Hi @A.Sanchez , unfortunately I can't reproduce the 500 error. I'm afraid that you need to debug the error message further yourself...

Comment: Hello @ArisS i have removed the 500 error. Your code work good. The only thing is i need to automate the process, since in my database I have many products.

As I told you, the script is to update the prices of a MySQL BBDD into the PrestaShop BBDD. 

In my MySQL BBDD, my products have the prestashop ID in the source_ID field.

How can I do it?

Comment: I have tried this code but getting problem on this like HTTP XML response is not parsable: array ( 0 => LibXMLError::__set_state(array( 'level' => 3, 'code' => 64, 'column' => 6, 'message' => 'XML declaration allowed only at the start of the document ', 'file' => '', 'line' => 2, )), ) could you please help me on this